# Rails - Using Tempfile to write on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I need to be able to write a temporary file for use during the request only.

Locally I can use the following successfully:

```
    tempfile = File.open(a.original_filename,'w')
    tempfile.write_nonblock(a.body)        
      paperclip stuff........
    tempfile.close
```

That works great, but not on Heroku... How can I do the above with Heroku's restrictions: [link text](http://docs.heroku.com/constraints#read-only-filesystem)

I'm not understanding how to translate the above into: `#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/myfile_#{Process.pid}`

Thanks for any help you can provide here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have a solution for you if you have to do stuff with paperclip. Include this class in your lib folder as heroku_compliant_file.rb

```
class HerokuCompliantFile < StringIO
  def initialize(str,filename,content_type)
    @original_filename = filename
    @content_type = content_type
    super(str)
  end
end
```

In your model containing the paperclip -

```
def insert_a_hunk_of_string_into_paperclip(some_object)
  f = HerokuCompliantFile.new(some_object.render,"myfile_#{Process.pid}","application/pdf")
  self.paperclip_model = f
  save
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `tempfile = File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/myfile_#{Process.pid}",'w')` ?

---

The correct syntax is `tempfile = File.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/myfile_#{Process.pid}",'w')` (see comments)

Comment: I Haven't tried that yet but can.. Problem is that I need that on production but not locally... any ideason how to solve for that?

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but that has myfile_ where I need it to be a.original_filename

Comment: Tried this tempfile = File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/#{a.original_filename}",'w') which errord with "Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - biz-stone.jpg):
"

Comment: Actually, it should probably be tempfile = File.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/#{a.original_filename}",'w') : you'll need to create the file. Also, you can test for `Rails.env.production?` to set the tempfile path differently for the production environment.

Comment: @David thanks, I think I've gotten to the point where I can create and write a file, now I need to figure out how to read it in paperclip via ":attachment => File.open(tempfile.read)" but that's erroring

Comment: Heroku dynos are a walled garden.  they cannot look over the wall at another dyno's file structure.  In fact public is statically initialize each time the dyno spins up based on your code, so nothing persist from day to day (they reset the dynos at least once a day).