# how to correctly use background job for file upload rails app heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job, background-process, sidekiq

i am working on a rails app that takes uploaded files from a user and pushes them to box. the issue is that this times out on some requests because the api call takes too long. i want to move this process to a worker process, but am not sure how to persist the file between the time the user uploads the file and the time the worker takes the job off the queue. all of the examples i have seen seem to skip this part or don't deal with using an api that is not s3. i thought about storing the file in the database, but the box api expects a file object (curl -F @file) and not just the contents of the file. any pointers on how this would be accomplished? i am looking to use sidekiq for performance reasons but delayed_job would be ok as well

Answer (score 2):

We just had similar issues few months for one of our project.
Check out following links for reference

http://mattgrande.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/delayedjob/

[Paperclip, Delayed Job, S3, Heroku - design for delayed processing of sensitive uploaded files: db or s3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479222/paperclip-delayed-job-s3-heroku-design-for-delayed-processing-of-sensitive)

Also there is one gem for paperclip with delayed job

https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/

Comment: is there any way to do this without going out to s3 first? seems like the only way to store the file data within the heroku system to be available to the worker is the database. if i was use to use the database for temporary file storage, would the preferred way be a text column and store the file data base64 encoded and then decode it,save it as a tempfile and then upload to box?

Comment: Not sure whether it will work because Heroku doesnot allow you to write.

Comment: Check out following link, it might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356582/rails-using-tempfile-to-write-on-heroku

Comment: I'm the author of that first link. First of all, thanks for the mention, I hope it helped you! That being said, that was written in 2009, so may not be 100% up to date. It should get you going, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on S3 to store your temporary files, you should take a look at the [paperclip_database](https://github.com/softace/paperclip%5fdatabase) gem.

We use it to store temporary files in our database to be processed by a delayed_job.

Simply pass a class with the attached temporary files to your delayed job and you're set. Like paperclip itself, the files will be deleted as soon as your job is deleted from the database.